# Does Technoshape Equipment work?

Tags: abdominals

Does Technoshape Equipment work? Has any one tried it?

I heard it is very expensive and the machine uses pressure pause therapy for stomach sculpting.

What is an alternative to it?

http://technoshape.net/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a newly hashed quack exercise product. In the 1950's there was the infamous "butt jigglers" which made the interesting claim that by "breaking up" the fat it could thereby cause it to go away. Vita Master was a popular product.

[image]

The only scientific evidence I found on their site consists of [a non applicable study done on rats](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15910955) talking about a barely-evident increase in fat metabolism due to increased blood flow. [The study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15910955) was looking at the muscles of [arterioles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arteriole), and the quack-product technoshape marketers then extrapolated out to say that it works the same in your abdomen.

Even if that was true by any significant margin, you're able to increase blood flow to your abdomen by nearly any exercise.

The product is a gimmick. If you want to be strong and lean look to nutrition and strength training.

Answer (score 0):

I have only found two reviews not by the company selling the Technoshape equipment:

- [The National](http://www.thenational.ae/lifestyle/well-being/do-these-products-make-trimming-down-easy) — "After one session, my stomach felt slightly more taut, although this may have been because I skipped breakfast that morning. Like the Hypoxi, some scientists are dubious to its claims of success. After all, a dozen sessions of any intensive exercise is bound to knock a bit of weight off."
- [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/08/12/how-to-get-a-flat-tummy_n_3695172.html) — "I lost 2.3cm from my waist and 2.5cm from my stomach. BUT I gained 2.4cm on my hips .... Although I'm sceptical it will give you a six-pack – you need to build up muscles for that – Technoshape did seem to tone and slim my stomach and if you’re not easily bored it is certainly an option worth trying to shift that stubborn stomach fat."